# Azure logic app converts hyphen-minus to _x002d_

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app which needs send the query result to given mail id. The issue is header columns contains like [data-01]. The logic app while sending the data it sends the csv like [data_x002d_01]. This is happening only in the columns. The values for the columns hyphens have no issues.

[image]

The csv sent to the email as below where you can see the hyphen is converted into *x002d*

[image]

How to avoid the conversion I want the column to be as like [vh-d]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Created logic app as shown below,
   [image]
2. In Execute SQL query action, selected required column as shown below,
   [image]
3. Create CSV csv table action, selected column type as **Custom**
4. Added **vh-d** as Header column and value as output of sql query.
   [image]
5. In send email action, added output of csv table as attachment.
   [image]
6. Logic app ran successfully,
   [image]
7. The attachment in mail has data as shown below,
   [image]